# WPF: Two depending ComboBoxes Binding Issues

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

**DATAMODEL**

A **PhotoPlace** has a **Country**. A Country has a list of potential regions (**AllRegions**) and one concrete region (**SelectedRegion**). The model holds a list of all available countries (**AllCountries**). The **CurrentPhotoPlace** the photo place which is currently shown in the UI.

**FUNCTIONALITY**

When you select a country from the combo box, the combo box with regions shall only show the regions belonging to the selected country. The **CurrentPhotoPlace.Country** and the **CurrentPhotoPlace.Country.SelectedRegion** shall be updated via the binding according the user selection.

**XAML**

```
<ComboBox Name="PhotoPlaceCountryComboBox"
          ItemsSource="{Binding AllCountries}"                
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPhotoPlace.Country, Mode=TwoWay}">
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox Name="PhotoPlaceRegionComboBox" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentPhotoPlace.Country.AllRegions}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"                                      
          SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPhotoPlace.Country.SelectedRegion}" >
</ComboBox>
```

**ISSUE**
The current solution does not work as soon as you select different countries.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: You model doesn't seem quite correct `SelectedRegion` should be a property of `CurrentPhotoPlace` not of a `Country` item.

Comment: That is maybe a design issue but was not the cause of the combo box issue (see comment below). I am also not sure if the selected region shall really belong the to photoplace, since the region is specific for the country.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code it's difficult to point the issue, but here is some possible causes :

- Your objects do not implement INotifyPropoertyChanged
- You don't raise PropertyChanged event when selecting country (setter of Country property in PhotoPlace)
- The SelectedItem is set with an instance that does not exist in ItemsSource

Comment: In fact I found the issue: Country object derives from a bases class. Both the base and the Country class override GetHashCode(). When I remove GetHashCode() from the Country class, it works fine.